# WP7 XNA Game 'stutters' when music repeats

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

At the beginning of a level in my XNA based game, I'm using MediaPlayer.Play() to play a .mp3 file and MediaPlayer.Repeating set to true to repeat the music.

When the music repeats, there is a considerable stutter in the game that is very annoying - the game essentially pauses, like it's waiting for the phone to find and play the music and then continues.

I tried to prevent this by setting MediaPlayer.Repeating to false and then just restarting the music manually (by detecting when it finished) and the stutter was still there.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening/ know how to fix it?

Edit:
This issue only occurs on the phone, not the emulator.

Comment: Do you get the same experience outside of an XNA game? I'm just curious if this is hardware specific and has more to do with the Zune player. There have been reports before of various devices having stuttering issues during music playback (particular at the end of songs), see this link here -> http://www.wpcentral.com/sound-stuttering-problems-samsung

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. It doesn't stutter on the emulator and I've only tried it on one phone (HTC Radar). The problem isn't the music stuttering, it's the GAME stuttering when the music repeats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I recommend having the sound managed in another thread so it wouldn't interfere with the  actual gameplay.  Parallel Threading?

Also check how you are loading the music also.  It might also be how you manage your music too.

Try debugging your method that repeats the music when you have it on your phone by setting break points to see what it does or even try going to Debug -> Start Windows Phone Performance Analysis and see what threads are active when the music repeats.

That's my two cents from a fellow 16 year old programmer :D